# Sinatra HTTP Auth: Different username/password for each subdomain

Tags: sinatra

I have implemented HTTP authorization to our Sinatra app, but now I'm trying to configure a different username/password for each subdomain of our app. For example: user1.mydomain.com uses different credentials than user2.mydomain.com. I need to have this configured before I run my app, but before I run my app, I don't have access to request.host. Any ideas on what I should do?

```
require 'sinatra'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  before do
    hostname = request.host
    namespace = hostname.gsub(".mydomain.com", "")
    unless namespace.empty?
      dir = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))
      auth_file = "#{dir}/config/auth/#{namespace}.yml"
      if File.exist?(auth_file)
        credentials = YAML.load_file(auth_file)
        use Rack::Auth::Basic do |username, password|
          username == credentials['username'] && password == credentials['password']
        end
      end
      redis = Redis.new(url: YAML.load_file("#{dir}/config/redis.yml")['url'])
      Split.redis = Redis::Namespace.new(namespace.to_sym, redis: redis)
    end
  end

  get '/' do
    # serve dashboard
  end
end

run MyApp
```

Comment: Another simpler way to solve my problem would be: How do I access the `request` object outside of a route? I need to read the hostname.

Comment: Does the above code not give you the host name? The request object is available in a before filter block.

Comment: It does give me the hostname but it's too late. I've already instantiated MyApp and what I need to do (because I didn't write the gem) is to configure MyApp with the hostname BEFORE it gets instantiated.

Comment: I put a breakpoint in just before `run MyApp` and what should work is: `Rack::Request.new(ENV).host`. But that just returns a colon (my request is being made to `localhost:9292`. No idea why I can't get the host.

Comment: Can you alter env vars on the server? Then you could set `hostname = ENV["MY_HOSTNAME"]` or somesuch.